# jQuery .hide() and CSS display:none; are not working on <option> element in Safair 9.0.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I've tried the same [code (and JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/s1ec5zuj/2/) in Firefox 44.0.2, Chrome 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit), and Safari 9.0.3 (on Mac OS X 10.11.3), and the only browser that has an issue with it is Safari.

Not only does `$(this).hide();` not work but neither does `$(this).addClass('hidden')` or `$(this).css("display", "none");`.

Has Safari just not yet caught up?

HTML:

```
<select name="responses" data-signature="randomString" size="12" style="width: 260px;">
    <option value="1" title="Title1" data-category="1" data-content="Content1">This is 1</option>
    <option value="2" title="Title2" data-category="1" data-content="Content2">This is 2</option>
    <option value="3" title="Title3" data-category="1" data-content="Content3">This is 3</option>
    <option value="4" title="Title4" data-category="0" data-content="Content4">This is 4</option>
    <option value="5" title="Title5" data-category="2" data-content="Content5">This is 5</option>
    <option value="6" title="Title6" data-category="2" data-content="Content6">This is 6</option>
    <option value="7" title="Title7" data-category="2" data-content="Content7">This is 7</option>
    <option value="8" title="Title8" data-category="1" data-content="Content8">This is 8</option>
    <option value="9" title="Title9" data-category="2" data-content="Content9">This is 9</option>
</select>
```

JS/jQuery (1.10.2):

```
$('select[name=responses]').children().each(function() {
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Incase it isn't obvious, the result of the JSFiddle should be an empty `<select>` element as all of the children (the `<option>` tags) should be set to `display: none;`.

Comment: apart from disabling, other alternative is dynamically filter and replace

Comment: You need to wrap the option in a `<span style="display:none">` i.e. `$(this).wrap(<span style="display:none"></span>);`